# how to implement a lexsort version of numpy.argpartition?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very long array 5 columns, 10 million rows. numpy.argpartition(x[:, 0], 10, axis=0) can give me the smallest 10 elements of first column. However, I would like to do the partition based on several columns. with lexsort I can do things like `numpy.lexsort(x[:,[3,2,0]].T)` To sort based on 0, then, 2, then 3 column. Is there canonical way to do this in argpartition?

If I want to use all columns, but use some column as major. I can use view to convert it to structed array:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15,3))
a_struct = a.view(dtype=[('a','int'),('b', 'int'), ('c', 'int')])
idx0 = np.partition(a_struct, 5, axis=0, order=['b', 'c'])
print(a[idx0.squeeze(), :].T)
```

However, the partition still use the rest fields not in the order. If I have more columns, the partition is much slower than an array only has 2 fields. I cannot create view with selected columns, because it requires continuous data.

I also noticed, unlike normal argpartition, if I use structed array, the result looks sorted completely.

```
[[32 82 51 92 40 36 46 19 25 31 26 82 11 91 46]
 [ 1 16 21 30 31 34 41 41 45 46 51 54 57 73 93]
 [17 55 55 93 42  5 13 34 69 13 71 65 53 62 24]]
```

if I only do partition on `a[:,1]` it is normal:

```
[ 1 16 21 30 31 34 54 41 45 51 57 41 46 73 93]
```

Comment: I doubt if anyone has worked out the details of performing such a partition.  While I haven't used `partition` much, it just feels like doing that kind of partial sort on several columns sequentially will involve a lot of ambiguity and complications.  If you don't see a `lexpartition` (or similar name) in the numpy documentation, there isn't such a thing.